# How to highlight a cell if the first column cells has a duplicate number when the second column cells has a different name

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

[image]

"CONTROL NUMBER" should be unique per "NAME"

I want to highlight the cells if the CONTROL NUMBER have duplicates if it corresponding name is different.

In the image above,
I have Control Numbers: 1,2,3 and Names A,B,C

1 - A , 3 - C, is not highlighted even though they are duplicates because the Control Number is unique per Name however 2 - B and 2 - A, is highlighted because both have the same Control Number '2' but they have different Names.

I want to know what formula I will use in the Conditional Formating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select column A.
- Enter "Formatting" - "Conditional formatting".
- Select "By formula".
- Enter the formula:

  ```
  =(COUNTIFS($A:$A,A1,$B:$B,B1)<>COUNTIFS($A:$A,A1))
  ```
- Set format as needed (red background in your case).
- Accept.

Now the cells in column A which matches your criteria will be marked.

Comment: This works as I expected! Great!

Answer (score -1):

For me, I use the formula  in the Conditional Formating:**=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$B$2:$B$7,$B2)=1**

[image]

Look, it's working well.

Comment: Your formula works with the given example, but it doesn't implement the logic described in the question. "I want to highlight the cells if the CONTROL NUMBER have duplicates if it corresponding name is different." (e.g. having for `1` twice with `B` and twice with `B` should be highlighted too, as different letters should not be assigned to the same number).